# How can I make an amplifier such that its gain increase proportional to the input difference

Tags: amplifier, differential

I want to make an amplifier that has a gain which increase with the difference between the inputs. For example:

1. If I have 2 volt difference between two input of the amplifier will have gain factor as 2.
2. If I have 5 volt difference between two input of the amplifier the gain factor will increase to 5.
   Is there such amplifier? What is its name? What is the key word to find such circuit?

Comment: This wouldn't be an amplifier, try lookingup analog multiplier,  squaring circuit, variable gain amp, log-antilog amp.

Comment: This is called a squaring circuit. Just feed the input to both input ports of an analog multiplier.

Comment: No. This is not the amplifier I am looking for. I won't feed the same voltage to both input. For example I will put 3 volts in the inverting input and 7 volt in the non invertint. The difference is 4 volt. Now I want the gain to be proportional to this difference not the voltage it self.

Comment: The gain of what? Which input is actually being multiplied by this variable gain? What is the ultimate output of this circuit supposed to be?

Comment: This is sounding like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what do you think you're going to achieve with such a circuit?

Comment: 3 and 7 is not the same V. totally illogical question

Comment: Hard to know what you mean. Variable gain amplifier maybe? VCA?

Comment: Unity gain differential amplifier followed by analog multiplier. But why would you need such a circuit??? What would be its purpose? In RF circuits, a nonlinear element such as a diode at a specific point in the transfer curve is sometimes used to get the square(x) function that you are looking for, but only at a very local bias point.

Comment: Thanks for all replys. But none of them is my answer. I want something that increase its gain with input difference. If the diference between two input is small I will have an amplifier with a low gain. But if the difference between two input big then the gain will increase. I have a PI controller. When I am far away from the set point I want the gain of proportional part to increase dramaticaly.

Comment: What are you trying to amplify?

Comment: You have just restated the behaviour of a squaring circuit!

Comment: VTC as unclear, a question should be able to be answered without endless clarification, make your questions specific.

Comment: What is the maximum frequency of interest in the input signal?

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you are actually asking.  A normal amplifier does:

OUT = A * IN

where A is the gain.  You want the gain to be proportional to IN, so:

OUT = IN * IN = IN<sup>2</sup>

In other words, you want a quadratic response, not a linear one.

The problem with this is that multiplying analog signals is difficult to do with good accuracy.  There are such things as analog multipliers.  You could put a analog multiplier in front of a fixed-gain amplifier to give you what you want.

You also need to decide whether you want 1 quadrant or 2 quadrant operation.  It's not clear whether your input signal can go negative.  That would make things more complicated.

There is a possible simplification since you are squaring a single signal instead of multiplying two arbitrary signals, and because the result is monotonic.  Back in the Pleistocene when you were stuck with only analog processing, diode function generators were used to create various monotonic functions with single inputs and single outputs.

However, back in today's real world, you should seek to do this kind of operation digitally if possible.  Determine what speed you need.  If a few 100 kHz sample rate is sufficient, then doing it digitally is a no-brainer.  That can be done in various common microcontrollers.  If over 1 MHz, you may need something like a high speed DSP.  Faster is possible with dedicated high speed A/Ds and a FPGA.